# how to debug Gradle sync failed, that has no other information alongside?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to build [Telegram's source code](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) on my machine, and it doesn't get built.

At first I didn't have NDK installed, so I installed that. Now I'm getting this very stupid error saying `Gradle sync failed` and giving me no more information whatsoever.

Here's what I tried so far, based on seeing answers in other questions:

- Invalidate cache / restart
- Deleting `.gradle` folder
- Restarting Android Studio
- Restarting computer

None of these steps solved the problem. The truly annoying thing is that it doesn't give me more information. That's very very annoying and stupid.

[image]

What should I do?

**Update**: Gradle console is completely empty. Not even one line is written there.

Comment: Don't you have a more verbose trace anywhere ?

Comment: @ToYonos, the problem is just that. I don't see any trace anywhere. That's what's annoying.

Comment: Could you manually build in command line with gradle ?

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Encountered exact situation where 'gradle sync failed' was the only message I was getting. No 'Messages' or error information.

So I did the following, opened the terminal from 'Android Studio' itself.

> Open the terminal from Android Studio
>
> gradlew tasks

This should list all the tasks that gradle can execution on project. If your project has not built properly you should get 'check'.

> gradlew check --stacktrace

The above command would give complete stacktrace about the issue and hopefully then you can troubleshoot. I could do it for my project

Edit :
In gradle.properties(root folder), you can add following :

> org.gradle.console=verbose
>
> org.gradle.logging.level=debug

Details : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Answer (score 1):

works for me using following code on macOS.

./gradlew tasks

and

./gradlew check --stacktrace

tks